# How to pass a collection of responses to a promise

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, future, promise

I want to pass  a collection of `Promise<WS.HttpResponse>` to the `waitAll` of the promise. So for example, instead of passing `r1`, `r2` and `r3`, I would want to add the to a list or collection and pass them to `waitAll`. Please help

public class AsyncTest extends Controller {

```
   public static void remoteData() {
    F.Promise<WS.HttpResponse> r1 = WS.url("http://example.org/1").getAsync();
    F.Promise<WS.HttpResponse> r2 = WS.url("http://example.org/2").getAsync();
    F.Promise<WS.HttpResponse> r3 = WS.url("http://example.org/3").getAsync();

    F.Promise<List<WS.HttpResponse>> promises = F.Promise.waitAll(r1, r2, r3);

    // Suspend processing here, until all three remote calls are complete.
    List<WS.HttpResponse> httpResponses = await(promises);

    render(httpResponses);
  }
}
```

Comment: sooo... do you want to merge the lists? that's what ur asking?

Comment: @LiranElisha I want to merge the reposnse because they could be more than 3, maybe like 180 and it wouldnt be right if i had to create r1 , r2, r3, r4, r5, r6.... r180. i would create all the promise request dynamically so i would want to pass a collection to the F.Promise.waitAll(somecollection). I am having difficulty in creating a collection of Responses to the Promise.waitAll method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so in order to hold several promises i would suggest simply to use a list. it's simple, easy, lots of example way to do things, and might be good here.
make a member

```
List<F.Promise<WS.HttpResponse>> newList = new ArrayList<F.Promise<WS.HttpResponse>>();
```

and a simple method

```
public static void addToList(F.Promise<WS.HttpResponse> x)
{
   newList.add(x);
}
```

and finally another simple method to make them wait

```
public static void makeThemWait()
{
   foreach(F.Promise<WS.HttpResponse> x:newList)
   {
       F.Promise.waitAll(x);
   }
}
```

let me know if it helped you or u need further help

Comment: It was a bit helpful. I would like to create an Iterable that can be passed to the Promise.waitAll() at once. Otherwise, i will have to deal with single responses from each call. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @JoeThames a HashSet is Iterable<Element>, you can use that. also, if my answer helped you please accept it

Comment: Can you help with the creation of this hash set. This is how the syntax looks like:                                              `code`public static <A> F.Promise<java.util.List<A>> waitAll(java.lang.Iterable<F.Promise<? extends A>> promises)

Comment: here is a simple example on using hashset: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/hashset_iterator.htm